# How can I pass the value to state in internal function on React(functional component)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { useEffectOnce } from 'usehooks-ts';
import { SportsTypeNavbar } from '../../../mobile/components'
import { getMatches } from '../../../store/actions/mobileSportsActions';
import './mHome.css'

function MHome(props) {

    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    const [timer, setTimer] = useState(null)
    const [isMounted, setIsMounted] = useState(false)

    const [sportTypeId, setSportTypeId] = useState(1);
    const [betradarCategoryId, setBetradarCategoryId] = useState(0);
    const [leagueName, setLeagueName] = useState();
    const [matchState, setMatchState] = useState('home');
    const [startIndex, setStartIndex] = useState(0);
    const [orderByLeague, setOrderByLeague] = useState(false);

    const get_Matches = useSelector(state => state.mobileSportsReducers.getMatches)
    const SportTypeList = useSelector(state => state.mobileSportsReducers.getTypeList);
    const dataFetch = () => {
        console.log('sportTypeId==>', sportTypeId); // sportTypeId -> undefined
        let obj = {
            sportTypeId: (sportTypeId !== undefined ? sportTypeId : 1),
            betradarCategoryId: betradarCategoryId,
            leagueName: leagueName,
            matchState: matchState,
            startIndex: startIndex,
            orderByLeague: orderByLeague
        }
        dispatch(getMatches(obj))
        clearTimeout(timer)
        setTimer(setTimeout(dataFetch, 5000))
    }
    useEffect(() => {
        if (!isMounted) {
            dataFetch()
            setIsMounted(true)
        }
    })
    useEffectOnce(() => {
        dataFetch()
    })
    const sportActiveFunc = (index) => { // sending props function from parent to child component
        setSportTypeId(index);
    }
    console.log('sportTypeId==>', sportTypeId); // output value -> 1
    return (
            <SportsTypeNavbar sportActiveFunc={sportActiveFunc} />
           )
};
export default MHome;
```

I am trying to set the value from state on this component for sending value by dispatch to server.
This value is coming from child component via sportActiveFunc function.
So here, I can get sportTypeId, but I can't get this state value on dataFetch function.
How can I get this state value?

Answer (score 0):

you can simply pass that as props in sportActiveFunc  funtion and have default value for it

like this:

```
const dataFetch = (id = sportTypeId  ) => {
       
        let obj = {
            sportTypeId: id ,
            betradarCategoryId: betradarCategoryId,
            leagueName: leagueName,
            matchState: matchState,
            startIndex: startIndex,
            orderByLeague: orderByLeague
        }
        dispatch(getMatches(obj))
        clearTimeout(timer)
        setTimer(setTimeout(dataFetch, 5000))
    }

 const sportActiveFunc = (index) => { 
            setSportTypeId(index);
            dataFetch(index) 
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I tried it by adding parameter on function. So it send and charge value first once.
It send once value, and next, it doesn't send first status. It send first initial state value.